# PostgreSQL iteration

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

i have been practicing how to *QUERY* a **PostgreSQL** database since am new to it, but am facing a challenge.
    i want to use a **key word** input to **query** my database, so that the (**input**) queries the database for the record of that animal, and (***prints***) only that (**ROW**) or it shows that it does not exist, but it has failed.

i am not exactly sure which is the right format to write down in python. but i do need help to solve this. & my table when it is produced, it comes out as a dis-organised list. i want each row to print on the next line, i have tried all i can think of, but it has failed too.

```
import os
import psycopg2.extensions


def clear_screen():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')


def begin():
    clear_screen()
    print("""
    OLD LIFE WILDLIFE CENTER!!!
        YOUR WELCOME
    """)
    input("press Enter/return to start£")
    clear_screen()


begin()


def quick_search():
    animal = input("keyWord search:.").lower()


class DatabaseConnection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.flash_db = psycopg2.connect(database='wildlife', user='postgres', password='poll£56', host='localhost')
        self.cur = self.flash_db.cursor()
        print("Database connected")

    def query_table(self):
         self.cur = self.flash_db.cursor()
         self.cur.execute('SELECT ID,NAME,LIVES,WEIGHT,LEGS ,CLASS,NUMBER,CATEGORY FROM CAGE')

        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        while True:
            print(rows)
            break


quick_search()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    database_connection = DatabaseConnection()
    database_connection.query_table()

clear_screen()
```

this is the result of **querying** THE database. Dis-organised.

```
keyWord search:.lion
Database connected
[(1, 'LION', 'DEN', '190                           ', 4, 
'CARNIVORES', 21, 'MAMMAL'), (2, 'TIGER', 'JUNGLE', '360                           
', 4, 'CARNIVORES', 2, 'MAMMAL'), (3, 'ZEBRA', 
'SAVANNAH', '180                           ', 4, 
'HERBIVORES', 90, 'MAMMAL'), (4, 'CHICKEN', 'PEN', '5                             
', 2, 'OMNIVORES', 1000, 'BIRDS'), (5, 'FISH', 'WATER', 
'3', 0, 'OMNIVORES', 10000,'FISH'), (6, 'SNAKES', 
'JUNGLE', '2.7', 0, 'OMNIVORES', 1, 'REPTILE'), (7, 
'CROCODILE', 'WATER', '400                           ', 
10, 'CARIVORES', 7, 'REPTILE')]
```

Comment: 1. What do you mean "disorganised"? Did you want a particular order of results, or did you want the rows formatted as a table? Or something else?

2. Are you aware you aren't actually searching for anything in your database query, just fetching all the results?

3. It is normally considered best practice to put function definitions at the top of your file and the actual calls `begin()` etc at the bottom. Put all the calls inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` statement

Comment: i wanted the rows formatted as a table, Yes.

Comment: so, should i change from **"fetchall()"**, to **"fetchone()"**

Comment: Well, if you want the results formatted as a table you will need to write some code to loop through them and format them. There's no magic way it will come out as you want.